# Scrollable flex child which shrinks when other sibling expands

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

I would like the .chat-box to shrink when the .typing-area expands upwards, which happens when you type in the .input-field and create multiple lines.

For some reason on the .chat-box if I do not set the maximum-height it overflows the .typing-area and this prevents this element from being fully flex.

Could I achieve what I want in pure css? otherwise, how can it be done with javascript?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.wrapper-chat {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 34rem;
}

.chat-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.chat-area header {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: green;
}

.chat-box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow-y: auto;

  padding: 1rem 3rem 2rem 3rem;
  background: white;
  border: 0.5rem solid #b8b6b6;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
}

.typing-area {
  padding: 1.8rem 3rem;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.typing-area .input-field {
  display: block;
  min-height: 4.5rem;
  max-height: 20rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;

  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper-chat">    
    <section class="chat-area">
      <header></header>
      <div class="chat-box"> 
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>         
      </div>
      <form  action="#" class="typing-area" >               
        <div class="input-field" contentEditable="true"></div>        
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself using css grid.

Enjoy!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}



.chat-area {
  width: 40rem;
  height: 34rem;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.chat-area header {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: green;
}

.chat-box {
  
  overflow-y: auto;

  padding: 1rem 3rem 2rem 3rem;
  background: white;
  border: 0.5rem solid #b8b6b6;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
}

.typing-area {
  padding: 1.8rem 3rem;
  display: flex;     

  background-color: green;
}

.typing-area .input-field {
  display: block;
  min-height: 4.5rem;
  max-height: 20rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;

  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
      
    <section class="chat-area">
      <header></header>
      <div class="chat-box"> 
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>         
      </div>
      <form  action="#" class="typing-area" >               
        <div class="input-field" contentEditable="true"></div>        
      </form>
    </section>
  
  </body>
</html>
```